# как сделать сетку с гибкими столбцами

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как реализовать такую сетку и при том что блоки будут генерировать и размер их зависит от содержимого и не обязательно они будут в таком виде. Пробывал реализовать через flex column wrap, но там нужно будет указать размер родительского блока учитывая что блоки разных размеров это становится проблематично.

Comment: Это трудно реализовать простым css, посмотрите в сторону masonry.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог найти решение